# Get client IP address from Azure Logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic app triggered by HTTP request and I would like to use the caller's IP address for logging and administration purposes in the workflow.

My HTTP headers received (shown by portal) only includes the following:

```
 "Host": "prod-101.westeurope.logic.azure.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0,(Windows NT 6.3; Microsoft Windows 6.3.9600; hu-HU),PowerShell/7.1.3",
    "Content-Length": "350",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
```

Is there any further setting to add "X-Forwarded-Host" to headers, or any other way to obtain the caller's external IP from the logic app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported natively by logic App, you can upvote the **[**`user voice`**](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/39780991-add-ability-to-see-client-ip-address-for-http-tri)** request here.

however you could pass the HTTP request to an Azure function within the LogicApp and use the logic below

```
#r "System.Web"

using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string clientIP = ((HttpContextWrapper)req.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"The client IP is {clientIP}");
}
```